# Insert data into OpenOffice database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, openoffice-base

I want to insert data into `OpenOffice` Database using Java.
i was able to fetch the data that i populated myself while creating the database, but I am not able to insert data into table using java code.
I used two methods.

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\database\\demo2");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from \"user\"");
while(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
}
```

This code works well when i fetch data.
I used following code to insert data.

```
rs.moveToInsertRow();
rs.updateString("name", "Dad");
rs.insertRow();
```

It didn't worked, then i tried:

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\database\\demo2");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
stmt.execute("insert into \"user\" values ( 'MyName' )");
```

It didn't worked as well, but no syntax error, then i tried:

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\database\\demo2");
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into \"user\" values ( 'MyName' )");
```

It also didn't worked as well, but no syntax error.

What should I do now? It is OpenOffice Database.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what does that mean?  Was there an exception?  If there was, please edit your question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: there is no exception... code compiled successfully.... when i execute it run well without amyproblem.... when i fetch data.... i get result.... but when i insert data it dont show any exception and reach at ending of code as well but my code dont save sata in database....
i dont know u understood my point or not... i m not good in english.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

stmt.execute("insert into \"user\" values ( 'MyName' )");

stmt.execute("shutdown");

Comment: Add some description to your answer.

Comment: I do not know English very well right now. if you want I'm write turkish, you translate google.